# Podman pull 'official' images from docker hub?

Tags: podman

No matter what I do, I only ever get a 404 or Error: invalid reference format

I think it should be podman pull hub.docker.com/_/postgres

but this doesn't work. I've also tried

```
podman pull hub.docker.com/postgres

podman pull hub.docker.com/__/postgres

podman pull hub.docker.com/library/postgres
```

Any ideas what's needed here to grab any of the official images from Docker Hub?

Comment: The `search` command would give you an answer, `podman search postgres`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In order to pull images from Docker Hub using `podman`, the image name needs to be prefixed by the `docker.io/` registry name.

To get the 'official images' they are part of the 'library' collection.

So to pull Postgres from Docker Hub using Podman, the command is

```
podman pull docker.io/library/postgres
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I get "connection reset by peer". I have also successfully logged in before.

Comment: "connection reset by peer" is usually a local network problem or firewall (especially corporate, possibly some ISPs) - you might have more luck on a different network or it might be something at Docker Hub. Sorry I can't help you with this

Answer (score 13):

Either follow the other answer and use a fully-qualified image name or you can add docker.io to your set of unqualified search registries:

`/etc/containers/registries.conf`

```
unqualified-search-registries = ["mylocalregistry:5005", "docker.io"]
```

This will make it possible to use `docker.io` as a fall back with unqualified image names like:

```
podman pull nginx
```

Comment: That works, but it needs to be:
```
unqualified-search-registries = ["mylocalregistry:5005", "docker.io"]
```

(dashes instead of underscores)